# Is anyone using pysmell for vim with luck?

Tags: vim, python, macvim

I'm trying to get pysmell (https://github.com/orestis/pysmell) to work - looks like a nice code completion tool for django development in vim.

I'm on Mac OS X 1.7.1 (Lion) with MacVim 7.3 (snapshot 61). My python version is 2.7.

Every time I try to invoke omnicompletion in a python file, I get these errors inside of MacVim (which is why it says `Press ENTER or type command to continue`):

```
Error detected while processing function pysmell#Complete:
line   24:
Traceback (most recent call last):
Press ENTER or type command to continue
Error detected while processing function pysmell#Complete:
line   24:
  File "<string>", line 7, in <module>
Press ENTER or type command to continue
Error detected while processing function pysmell#Complete:
line   24:
  File "<string>", line 3, in vimcompletePYSMELL
Press ENTER or type command to continue
Error detected while processing function pysmell#Complete:
line   24:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages
/pysmell/idehelper.py", line 56, in findPYSMELLDICT
Press ENTER or type command to continue
Error detected while processing function pysmell#Complete:
line   24:
    tryReadPYSMELLDICT(directory, 'PYSMELLTAGS', PYSMELLDICT)
Press ENTER or type command to continue
Error detected while processing function pysmell#Complete:
line   24:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages
/pysmell/idehelper.py", line 42, in tryReadPYSMELLDICT
Press ENTER or type command to continue
Error detected while processing function pysmell#Complete:
line   24:
    updatePySmellDict(dictToUpdate, eval(tagsFile.read()))
Press ENTER or type command to continue
Error detected while processing function pysmell#Complete:
line   24:
  File "<string>", line 0
Press ENTER or type command to continue
Error detected while processing function pysmell#Complete:
line   24:

Press ENTER or type command to continue
Error detected while processing function pysmell#Complete:
line   24:
    ^
Press ENTER or type command to continue
Error detected while processing function pysmell#Complete:
line   24:
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

Can anyone recognize this error/see what's wrong and help me solve it? This really does look like a nice tool for pythong/django/whatever python lib omnicompletion and I would like to try it out.

EDIT: removed all the `Press ENTER or type command to continue` messages

```
Error detected while processing function pysmell#Complete:
line   24:
Traceback (most recent call last):
Error detected while processing function pysmell#Complete:
line   24:
  File "<string>", line 7, in <module>
Error detected while processing function pysmell#Complete:
line   24:
  File "<string>", line 3, in vimcompletePYSMELL
Error detected while processing function pysmell#Complete:
line   24:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages
/pysmell/idehelper.py", line 56, in findPYSMELLDICT
Error detected while processing function pysmell#Complete:
line   24:
    tryReadPYSMELLDICT(directory, 'PYSMELLTAGS', PYSMELLDICT)
Press ENTER or type command to continue
line   24:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages
/pysmell/idehelper.py", line 42, in tryReadPYSMELLDICT
Error detected while processing function pysmell#Complete:
line   24:
    updatePySmellDict(dictToUpdate, eval(tagsFile.read()))
Error detected while processing function pysmell#Complete:
line   24:
  File "<string>", line 0
Error detected while processing function pysmell#Complete:
line   24:

Error detected while processing function pysmell#Complete:
line   24:
    ^
Error detected while processing function pysmell#Complete:
line   24:
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```